# Transition background image size only, in css? (When background size is not set)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a background image with background-size cover and want it to animate when  I hover over the container. I know how I would do if the background-size was set to a specific pixel number but I need it to do the same when it's set to cover. Something like calc(cover*1-3). I got it working by resizing the container instead and changing the z-index. Hovewer this solution does not look good since it changes the z-index somewhere in the middle of the transition.

What it looks like now: https://gyazo.com/98dc31d372f10c4896ff3c783aa436dd

Any suggestions? Jquery welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Here's my HTML:

```
<section class="photo-grid-static">
    <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza1.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza3.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('Images and videos/odesza2.png');"></div>
</section>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.photo-grid-static {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    padding: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.photo-grid-container { 
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.photo-grid-container:hover{
    z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your ".photo-grid-container" divs with a div that has a "overflow: hidden" property.

```css
.photo-grid-static {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    padding: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.photo-grid-static > div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo-grid-container { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.photo-grid-container:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

```html
<section class="photo-grid-static">
  <div>
    <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('http://odesza.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/1920-1080.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('http://odesza.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/1920-1080.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="photo-grid-container" style="background-image: url('http://odesza.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/1920-1080.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah that'd do the trick! However. Is there a more clean solution with less divs? :)

Comment: You can't use keywords (such as cover) when using CSS animations for background-size. If you want to remove the extra divs, you need to deal without the cover property and set instead a real size. Do you want I edit my answer with this solution ?

Comment: I've ended up using your solution. Of course I'll accept :)